# convert S4 DataFrame of Rle objects to sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, r-s4

In the R language, I have an S4 DataFrame consisting of Rle encoded elements.
The data can be simulated using following code

```
x = DataFrame(Rle(1:10),Rle(11:20),Rle(21:30))
```

Now, I want to convert this DataFrame to a sparse matrix from the Matrix package. On a usual data.frame, one can do

```
Matrix(x,sparse=TRUE)
```

However, this does not work for DataFrames, as it gives the following error:

```
Matrix(x,sparse=TRUE)
```

`Error in as.vector(data) :`
 `no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector`

Any ideas on how to convert between data types in a rather efficient way?

Thanks!

Comment: `Matrix(as.data.frame(x))`; DataFrame and Rle are from Bioconductor S4Vectors package, so it's probably appropriate to ask questions about them on the [Bioconductor support site](https://support.bioconductor.org).

Comment: @MartinMorgan Thank you for the reply, however this does not work. It returns the error `Error in asMethod(object) : invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_geMatrix` .
I will try it on the Bioconductor support site, too.

Comment: My question was answered on the bioconductor support site: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/66586/#66623

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting Michael Lawrence's [answer](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/66586/#85609) here to avoid the link breaking. Also it needed a small bug fix to handle the case when a Rle ends with zero:

```
# Convert from Rle to one column matrix
#
setAs("Rle", "Matrix", function(from) {
    rv <- runValue(from)
    nz <- rv != 0
    i <- as.integer(ranges(from)[nz])
    x <- rep(rv[nz], runLength(from)[nz])
    sparseMatrix(i=i, p=c(0L, length(x)), x=x,
                 dims=c(length(from), 1))
})


# Convert from DataFrame of Rle to sparse Matrix
#
setAs("DataFrame", "Matrix", function(from) {
  mat = do.call(cbind, lapply(from, as, "Matrix"))
  colnames(mat) <- colnames(from)
  rownames(mat) <- rownames(from)
  mat
})
```

Comment: Sadly it does not work anymore because `as.integer` now fails on `IRanges` objects with error `Error in as.vector(x, mode = "integer") :   no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector`. Does anybody has a workaround?